# How does one say in English 'one loses essential tool of one's trade'?

Tags: phrase-requests

In Chinese there is a idiomatic saying 'like a Mandarin who lost his seal' (做官的把印丢了） which generalises to really mean one who lost the essential tool of one's trade (and thereby not limited to those serving in (imperial) Chinese administration).  Is there a rough equivalence in English,

Comment: An essential tool of one’s trade could refer to a license, an actual tool or tools, or a physical skill.  Which do you mean, or is it metaphoric?

Comment: actual tool, but also the license or proof authority (like the seal of a mandarin conferred upon him by higher authorities)

Comment: Doctors and lawyers sometimes lose their licenses for legal reasons, but I can’t recall a saying.